# How to access object displayed in ListView after changing it's property in DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an aspx page containing ListView, where for each item user may choose one of enumerated values.

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvEmployeesList" >
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartments" runat="server" Visible='<%# VisibleForAdmin %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Department1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Department2" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        lvEmployeesList.DataSource = LogicTest.GetEmployeesList();
        lvEmployeesList.DataBind();
        }

    }
    protected void ddlDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ;
    }
```

ListView displays collection of `UserData` objects.

I want to access the `UserData` object, for wchich Department selection was changed in ddlDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged method and I see no elegant way to do it. I'd appreciate any help with that issue. :)

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see what you have when selected index changed? For example what you have in `lvEmployeesList.SelectedValue` or `lvEmployeesList.Items[lvEmployeesList.SelectedIndex].DataItem`?

Comment: SelectedIndex is set to -1 which is not a surprise since I don't select anything on EmployeesList.

Comment: But on selectedIndexChange event you will be selected anything right? It's not the surprise that you wont get selected item data if haven't selected anything.